# Windshield wiper only making contact on the ends of the blade

Tags: windshield-wipers

My windshield wiper will NOT clean anything off except for the ends.  My wiper arm was cracked at the bottom, so I replaced the entire arm.  While I was at it, I replaced the entire wiper.  Everything is brand new!!  And it still does not touch the windshield in the middle of the blade to clean it.  I am SO frustrated!!  I can't see at all in the rain!!  Help?

Comment: Pictures would help - Rory suggested the spring at the base of the wiper arm (near where the whole assembly pivots to wipe the windscreen).  A picture of the wiper itself might help as well - maybe something is bent.

Answer (score 6):

When you replaced the wiper, you may have inadvertently damaged or released the spring which pulls the wiper blade towards the windscreen. Depending on what type of car you have, this could be of various different types but you usually find it at the wiper pivot. When you try to pull the wiper away from the glass does it resist?

An alternative is that you may have fitted the wrong type of wiper blade - have you checked it is compatible.

Have a look in the user manual to identify the spring or tensioner for your vehicle, and check.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like there isn't enough tension in the arm.

Answer (score 1):

if you really care about what your car looks like, what you do to it and/or what others think or say about your ride please disregard this option but it's free, quick and you dont have to replace anything:

- If you have a steel windshield wiper arm and the wiper is experiencing little contact with the windshield, just bend the windshield arm about 4 inches away from the link tip (to assure you don't mess up the connector). Bend it about 2 to 3 degrees (not too much) and thats it. my trucks been good for months now.
- You'll need pliers and a monkey wrench (or whatever helps you sleep at night) for a precise bend.
- 2 minutes tops.

Answer (score 0):

I have had many contact issues with the OEM style metal frame wiper blades. They make the worst contact and are also the worst performers in snow/ice because the internal linkage instantly gets bound and clogged.

I prefer to use a beam style wiper blade. They are more expensive but they work much much better. I use Trico NeoForm blades and they work great. If you are concerned about the price (it is recommended to change wipers every 6months) you can actually remove them from the vehicle during the dry seasons and throw on the stock crappers during that time to prevent the rubber from drying in the sun. You will get more mileage out of the wipers this way if you are willing to change them before and after your wet seasons. Doing this, I bet you could easily get 2+ years out of a set of high quality wipers.

First make sure the wiper arm is giving adequate downforce though.